# how to override adminhtml/Order.php

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

How can I override Order.php  need to change button text for `create new order`, 
please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order` block to achieve this. Just use the locale translation csv in this case `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv`
and add the new label there.

**Example:**
`"Create New Order","Create New Order Edited"`

**Screenshot in the admin:**

[image: Create New Order button]

Answer (score 1):

Of course if just for changing a text button, It's useless to rewrite all this, you should go to : `app/local/{yourlanguage_Code}/Mage_Sales.csv` then change `"Create New Order","Your new button text"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order block to achieve this. Just use the locale translation csv in this case app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv and add the new label there.

Of course if just for changing a text button, It's useless to rewrite all this, you should go to : app/local/{yourlanguage_Code}/Mage_Sales.csv then change "Create New Order","Your new button text"

Example: "**Create New Order**","**Create New Order Edited**"